# General Shapes Of Graphs In Higher / Lower Dimensions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, graphing-functions

This may be a silly question, but I am curious as to what graphs generally look like in different dimensions.

If you think about it, the basic number line can be thought of as the space in $ℝ^1$, so it could be argued that a "graph" in $1D$ results in a single point.

Most of us probably know that the graph in $2D$ results in a curve in $ℝ^2$.

And a graph in $3D$ results in a surface in $ℝ^3$.

From taking multi-variable calculus, I believe a graph in $4D$ results in a solid in $ℝ^4$ but I could be mistaken there.

But I am not sure what comes after a solid for a graph in $5D$. A tesseract maybe? And of course the dimensions after that I am unsure of as well.

And is it possible to go the other way, where we go below the First Dimension? Does the idea of $0D$ or even negative dimensions exist?

So I guess my question is this: is there any sort of "hierarchy" of this sort of thing? Such as:

...->_____ ->Point -> Curve -> Surface -> Solid ->_____ ->...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by graph?

Comment: By graph I mean the shape of the functions in the $nth$ dimension. For example, the graph of a function in $2D$, like $f(x) = x^2$, the "graph" is in the shape of a curve. And going up a dimension, the graph of the function $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$  is in the shape of a surface.

Comment: I ask because there's more than one way to specify an object an object in a given space.  In $\Bbb R^3$ for instance, I could define $\mathbf r(t) = (1,0,2)+t(3,4,5)$ which is a *curve* not a *surface*.

Comment: The generalization of the things you're talking about are **smooth manifolds**.  A connected $0$-dimensional smooth manifold is called a point.  A connected $1$-dimensional smooth manifold is called a curve.  Etc.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now. Perhaps I should change how I am asking this then. I guess what I'm asking is what the shape of functions with $n$ independent variables are.

Comment: And I'm unfamiliar with smooth manifolds but I will take a look at them to see if that helps me.

Comment: Then yes.  A function $f(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)$ always describes an $n$-dimensional space (as that's basically what $n$-dimensional means -- that it requires $n$ variables to specify any given point).